# Directshow: setting MPEG2VIDEOINFO extra info for MEDIASUBTYPE_HVC1

Tags: directshow, hevc, h.265, lavfilters

I've wrapped the x265 code into a DirectShow filter and can't get the video to playback with LAV Filters.

I can't find any documentation from Microsoft with respect to how the MPEG MPEG2VIDEOINFO should be filled in when outputting MEDIASUBTYPE_HVC1 so I've tried using a similar to [H.264](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/h-264-video-types).

[image]

Connection is fine, but playback results in a black window.

In the GraphStudioNext property window I see a "HEVC Decoder Configuration Record" structure but the values output by my filter don't look right.[image]

Does anyone know how to set the extra data of the MPEG2VIDEOINFO header? A link to some documentation on how this should be configured would be great as well.

Comment: Never had to deal with H.265 in DirectShow, but I would say that NAL units in media type (the line on first image "Sequence Header" with binary data) should be prefixed with 16-bit length, ass opposed to 32-bit now.

Comment: Thanks @RomanR., will give that a try.